# The model's error value comes through fine, but th:error does not work

Tags: html, spring, dependency-injection, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot’s validation.

The value comes through fine in the controller, but I used `th:error` to print in Thymeleaf, but the value is not printed. Also, in case of an error, the specified class is also not set.

This is Thymeleaf code

```
<form role="form" action="/signup" th:object="${memberForm}" method="post" id="singin_form">
        <label>
            <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR EMAIL</p>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="email" class="input" id="emailInput" th:field="*{email}">
            </div>
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errorclass="fieldError" th:errors="*{email}"></p>
        </label>
```

And this is a printed value that is saved and passed from the controller to the model.

`{valid_rePasswd=password error., valid_email=email error.}`

Just in case, I'll also attach the contents of the controller.

```
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String createUser(@Valid MemberFormDto memberForm, Errors errors, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("memberForm", memberForm);

            Map<String, String> validatorResult = userService.validateHandling(errors);
            for(String key : validatorResult.keySet()){
                model.addAttribute(key, validatorResult.get(key));
            }

            System.out.println(validatorResult);

            return "singin";
```

How can I solve it? I've done almost everything I can.